# Reference: control theory

Tags: reference-request, control-theory, optimal-control

I'm looking for suggestions on books or reviews on control theory, if possible written in a fairly modern language and not excessively technical on the math side.

In particular, I would need the following topics covered

- Optimal control: LQR, LQG
- Kalman theory, time series, poles, etc.
- Robust control

I'm already familiar with the general ideas.

Comment: What do you mean with Kalman theory, since the Kalman filter is already captured by LQG and the main thing left would be the Kalman decomposition?

Comment: I know the Kalman filter is the "estimation" part of the LQG. What I mean is details on the Kalman alone, related concepts as arma models and so on, and later on a proof/discussion of the separation LQG = Kalman + LQR.

Answer (score 0):

For robust control, I suggest ***"Robust Control Design with MATLAB" by Da-Wei Gu*** which I found quite practical. And you can read ***"Essentials Robust Control" by Kemin Zhou*** for deeper theories